How can I query a percentage field in Looker for percentages above a threshold when the field appears to be a string?
I am trying to add a Lookr filter which gives me a subset of mailings with high open rates, however the field is clearly not a number since operators like greater than or smaller than don't work.

When I use the "greater than 30" the result I get is empty.


Is there a way to convert the value in that field into a number so I can use the "greater than" operator?
Expected to get a subset of the results with open rates greater than 30. I got empty results.

You can use a calculated field to substract the full number (without decimal or %) and use that calculated field to filter the emails based on open rate
